# preg_match on a number between variable whitespace and a fixed string

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to come up with a regular expression that will qualify on the `25` in this string:

```
Always       -       25 (Lifetime
```

The amount of space between the `-` and the `25` can be variable, but the trailing `(Lifetime` will always be there.

I've tried this: `preg_match('/\s(.*)\s\(Lifetime',$sString,$aMatch);` but it qualifies on the `25` and everything preceding it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
preg_match('~\s+(\d+)\s\(Lifetime~', $sString, $aMatch);
```

It matches one or more space characters, followed by a number and finally the `(Lifetime` string.

Comment: Works like a charm--so if I understand correctly that plus sign indicates "one or more" whether it be whitespace `\s` or a digit `\d`?